# Calling servlet jquery ajax 404

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets

I am beginner to java servlets, I am creating basic servlet examples,

I created .html file. in which I write jquery ajax call to servlet

Here is the web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>NewServlet2</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>NewServlet2</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>NewServlet2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/NewServlet2</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

JS Script:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("HERE");
            $.ajax({
                url: "newServlet2",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (responce) {
                    alert(responce);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The response is 404. I don't know what is wrong here.

Please help me.

Comment: Added scripts in question

Comment: is the servlet container running

Comment: Yes, Servlet is running

Comment: what url are you calling for this page in browser